# Neo4j query improvization

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

How can I Optimise below query

```
match (e1Server:Server) where e1Server.name='XYZ' 
optional match (e1Server)-[r1:AFFINITY]-(n1Server:Server)
optional match (n1Server:Server)-[r2:AFFINITY]-(n2Server:Server) where id(e1Server) <> id(n2Server)
optional match (n2Server:Server)-[r3:AFFINITY]-(n3Server:Server) where id(e1Server) <> id(n3Server) and id(n1Server) <> id(n3Server) 
optional match (n3Server:Server)-[r4:AFFINITY]-(n4Server:Server) where id(e1Server) <> id(n4Server) and id(n1Server) <> id(n4Server) and id(n2Server) <> id(n4Server) 
return distinct e1Server,n1Server,n2Server,n3Server,n4Server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
MATCH p=(s:Server)-[:AFFINITY*..4]-(:Server)
WHERE
  s.name = 'XYZ' AND
  ALL(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(p)-1) WHERE
    NONE(j IN RANGE(i+1, LENGTH(p)) WHERE NODES(p)[i] = NODES(p)[j]))
RETURN NODES(p)
```

Also, if it is valid to make the `-[:AFFINITY*..4]-` relationship pattern directional (by putting an arrow on one end), then the query should be even faster.

[UPDATE]

Based on your comments, I will assume below that the relationship pattern is changed to be directional and to use a reduced upper bound of 3. To get a result closer to your original results:

```
MATCH p=(s1:Server)-[:AFFINITY*..3]->(s2:Server)
WHERE
  s1.name = 'XYZ' AND
  (LENGTH(p) = 3 OR NOT (s2)-[:AFFINITY]->(:Server)) AND
  ALL(i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(p)-1) WHERE
    NONE(j IN RANGE(i+1, LENGTH(p)) WHERE NODES(p)[i] = NODES(p)[j]))
RETURN NODES(p)
```

This query returns results for the longest paths that do not exceed the bound.

Comment: thanks for your response but your query didn't improve any performance..its taking same time as of the one I posted :)

Comment: How much data do you have, and how slow is it?

Comment: I have around 20k Server nodes,query ran for 4 minutes and then the connection lost.

Comment: Since variable-length relationship searches have exponential complexity (based on the path length), you could try lowering the upper bound to 3 (if acceptable).

Comment: Yeah..its very quick with length 3 and directional relationship.is there away I can alter the query to get result like mentioned in the question (return distinct e1Server,n1Server,n2Server,n3Server,n4Server).

Comment: if i want to make it work for 4,can i just replace 3 with 4 in the updated query.Will it work or will there be any missing data? because tried with bound 4,this time its quick with the updated query

Comment: Yes, you would need to replace both `3` values with `4`.

Comment: Thank u so much @cybersam